# DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(
    ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Context.Response.Write("selectedindexchanged")
End Sub
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: You have your answer, but in the future you really should provide clear information about *what* isn't working. Otherwise it's just guesswork, like the provided answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you put Autopostback = true for the dropdown list

Comment: Google will have more answers to how to set autopostback = true.

Comment: @Edwin It's still considered good (if not even best) practice to post a *complete* answer that requires little looking elsewhere for further information. Answers should help you get to your solution, not just provide hints or redirection-links.